# Ambari server LDAP setupp error

Tags: ldap, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, data-security

I've been trying to setup lambda for data security in hadoop(hortonworks), the command and inputs provided are as follows:

[svb_cluster@VSL080ALTISVB03 certs]$ **sudo ambari-server setup-ldap**
Using python  /usr/bin/python
Setting up LDAP properties...
    Primary URL* {host:port} (192.168.68.22:389):
    Secondary URL {host:port} (192.168.85.35:389):
    Use SSL* [true/false] (false):
    User object class* (posixAccount):
    User name attribute* (uid):
    Group object class* (posixGroup):
    Group name attribute* (cn): user
    Group member attribute* (memberUid):
    Distinguished name attribute* (dc):
    Base DN* (cn=SVBProjectAmbari,cn=users,dc=altimetrik,dc=com):
    CN=SVBProjectAmbari,CN=Users,DC=altimetrik,DC=com
    Referral method [follow/ignore] : ignore
    Bind anonymously* [true/false] (true):

====================

## Review Settings

Save settings [y/n] (y)?
Saving...done
Ambari Server 'setup-ldap' completed successfully.

now, when I try this command for syncing:
**sudo ambari-server sync-ldap  --existing**

and enter ambari admin login password, i get the following error:

**Syncing all...ERROR: Exiting with exit code 1.
REASON: Caught exception running LDAP sync. Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090749, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580]; remaining name 'CN=SVBProjectAmbari,CN=Users,DC=altimetrik,DC=com'**

Kindly, recommend a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090749, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580

Anonymous bind is not allowed by you ldap server. Therefore in the ldap set up command you need to provide

1. Bind anonymously -> false
2. Manager DN -> user dn , like cn=xyz,ou=gh,dc=ab,dc=com
3. Manager Password -> user password